# Ubuntu 18.04 wifi doesn't work after update

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Precision M6400. When first installed 18.04, WiFi was running fine. After automatic update, it doesn't any more.
WLan spots are displayed correctly, but when trying to connect it fails after about 1 min, a message appears: Connection failed.
Updated and upgraded already, but no success. Looks, like the driver / firmware is no more correct after update.
Any hints?

```
$ lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5761e Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1680] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell NetXtreme BCM5761e Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1028:0251]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1321]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

--

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ uname -r
4.15.0-33-generic
```

After switching back to kernel 4.15.0.32.35 it doesn't detect the wifi adapter resp. doesn't start up the driver iwlwifi.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5761e
Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1680] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell NetXtreme BCM5761e Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1028:0251]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1321]

$ rfkill list
$
```

Comment: Sorry if I am asking the obvious...but have you tried a full shutdown & turn back on? I've had a couple of updates recently where I've had to do that after the update seemed to break something (not the same as your problem though).

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `uname -r` If you interrupt the boot process at the GRUB menu and boot into an earlier kernel version, is the issue solved?

Comment: @B.Tanner: Yes, shut down many times in between.

Comment: @chili555: tried to boot into earlier kernel, both normal or recovery mode. Not successful, it didn't boot up. Locked up in an endless loop. Thanks so far.

Comment: Can you temporarily connect with ethernet and try: `sudo apt install  --reinstall linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic` and then try the GRUB menu again?

Comment: @chili555: reinstall 4.15.0.32 worked and can be selected in GRUB menue. But then, wifi adapter is not recognized. Seems like the driver is not loaded? See listing above.

Comment: Is there any improvement after: `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-32-generic` I believe it is required but I thought it would get automatically installed as a dependency of linux-image. Any clues here? `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

Comment: I tried the following: Downloaded driver iwlwifi-5000-ucode-5.4.A.11, unzipped the tar archive and copied as user root to /lib/firmware.
cp iwlwifi-5000-ucode-5.4.A.11 /lib/firmware
that worked, the directory was there
after that I ran
modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi

Unfortunately still not successfull.
For the moment I think, I stick to wired connection and wait for the ultimate hint or for the next update that hopefully may fix the problem. Thanks for all input up to now.